# automate spfx packaging including selected components

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Description and objectives:

I am trying to figure out a "best practice" guidance on this topic:

We are planning to create a "self-service" packaging solution, the idea behind is sort of selecting a subset of spfx components and generating the solution only with the selected components.

An example:

- spfx solution containing 20 webparts,
- user selects 5 of them
- packaging gets generated only with the 5 componentes selected, the rest of them are not included in the packaging.

P.S. Notice that I am not talking about sharing code between spfx components, more in terms of finding out a way to automate the process so that a heldesk non technical person would be able to generate the solution (including only the components that were paid off)...

Answer (score 2):

For this scenario you have to build a asp.net server side interface which will modify / manipulate your config.json file.

step 1 : Create a UI for selection of number of web parts with check box.

On each selection manipulate the config.json file in back end.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/config.2.0.schema.json",
  "version": "2.0",
  "bundles": {
    <<manipulate this section>>
  },
  "externals": {},
  "localizedResources": {
    <<manipulate this section>>
  }
}
```

step 2 : Use a button to initiate the build and package process from back-end.

```
gulp clean
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

Step 3 : Finally enable a link in the UI once the solution got generated. This link should point to your package file which was generated in the server.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to edit/update the `config/config.json` file in the SPFx solution before building the package for the solution. The `components` array in the `bundles` object defines which components will be bundled as part of the solution.

You could edit the `config.json` and then run the gulp tasks to build the package.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/config.2.0.schema.json",
  "version": "2.0",
  "bundles": {
    "hello-world-web-part": {
      "components": [
        {
          "entrypoint": "./lib/webparts/helloWorld/HelloWorldWebPart.js",
          "manifest": "./src/webparts/helloWorld/HelloWorldWebPart.manifest.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "externals": {},
  "localizedResources": {
    "HelloWorldWebPartStrings": "lib/webparts/helloWorld/loc/{locale}.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web Parts are defined in `config.json`, package is defined in `package-solution.json`. You could create a set of `config.json` and `package-solution.json` for each customer.

The easiest approach to achieve the kind of separation you mentioned would be to create two separate projects.

**Unfortunately you don't have such granular control in SPFx. Separating them out to different projects would be a more robust approach.**

Comment: That's what I thought... So anyone seeing this question want to collaborate to create some kind of UI wrapper that is able to select webparts from a config.json file and then create the package solution? I am open to ideas (I was planning to use a combination of powershell and generate the UI from it also)